# whether i can DownGrade the In-APP Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

In my In-APP purchase, i am using non-renewing In-APP Purchase I have to Favorites the Stocks.
there are three level 25 stocks,50 stocks,100 stocks.
My question is whether i can Downgrade my purchase from 100 stocks to 50 stocks in current month

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No". BUT, as always if you as a developer have done a good job and are keeping track of the purchases, you could (with a lot of work from your server-side) basically downgrade server-side. THIS IS NOT TO PREFER THOUGH, SINCE IT VIOLATES APPLES GUIDELINES. But that still means the user would have to buy a new package. Apple do not allow you to make purchases outside of their sandboxed environment. 
Apple also have a form on their website which allows you to get a re-found if for example your kids by all the love they give, have made a purchase which they shouldn't have done. This request is sent to the app-developer also. This method will probably also be removed in the future since there are lots of ways preventing this from happening from your device settings.

So, again. The answer is sadly no. But with ways of getting them back via Apple support for a limited time and if the purchase have been made by kids for example. You can't downgrade.

Comment: thnx for the answer...:)

Comment: 1)It means i can not buy the 50 stocks package if i bought 100 stocks package.and 2)what if my 100 stock package is  over in current month n i want to buy any other package may be 25 stock or 50 stocks.